# Shift key on Bluetooth keyboard won't work

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

The shift key on my Bluetooth keyboard won't work. It is especially annoying when typing passwords. I have a Rocketfish Bluetooth Keyboard. I remember fixing this problem but I'm not sure how.

Comment: i have the same keyboard with the same problem, running 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me with the same keyboard, running Ubuntu 13.04

System Settings-> Universal Access-> Typing-> Turn sticky keys on